# Change text color in Chrome browser header in android

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser, meta-tags, meta

I have used meta tag in the header to set the theme-color in an html page. it works perfectly fine, but the text color is black, i want it to be white. Do we have a solution for this?

`<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">`

This changes header background color. Please help me with text color, if you have any idea.